# How can we call Ajax "error: function()" function manually from success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**How can I call error: function manually from success:function ? Is it possible ?**

```
success: function(data) {
    response($.map(data, function(item) {
      if (item != "some value") {
        // Call error:function from here 
      }
      return item;
    }))
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    alert(err.Message);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Create a function `onSuccess()` move the code of current `success` to it and assign it as `success: onSuccess, error: ...` then you can invoke it without ajax as well.

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood the concept of error callback in ajax. There might be other better options for your issue if you add some more detail in your question.

Comment: Side note: not sure why you would need to do `eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")")` but there's a 99% chance that it should be done some other way without eval.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    response($.map(data, function(item) {
        if (item != "some value") {
            onError(...) 
        }
        return item;
    }))
},
error: onError


var onError = function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    alert(err.Message);
}
```

By the way, to use eval is never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

**success** is A function to be called if the request succeeds

**error** is A function to be called if the request fails
So with that in the background your question does not make sense.

But yes you may have common things to do when either a call succeeds or fails; my suggestion is to collect all the common things to do in a separate function and call this common function in both success and error

Answer (score 1):

Ajax `error` function is called when the http request fails. The `error` function cannot be triggered on ajax `success`. Refer API Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

If you want to do a specific task, that you intend to do on ajax `error`, you can wrap it in a function and call it inside the ajax `success`.